# Display table from assets folder on the selection of spinner in dynamic RecyclerView

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm new to Android and I've got a database in assets folder, which has six tables and each table has total six columns and one column has BLOB datatype.

In a Activity, I've placed a Spinner. The work of Spinner is that if a user selects an option, a new Activity will open which shows the content of a table that the user has selected in Spinner.

For example, if you select Hollywood Stars in  Spinner, the contents of the table "hollywoodstars" (Photo of the star and name) will be shown in another activity in a dynamic RecyclerView.

Now the questions I've:

1. how to read content from database as per user's Spinner choice and
2. how to display it in RecyclerView?

**Registration.java-**

```
public class Registration extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    EditText t1,t2,t3;
    Spinner sp;
    String sploc,loc;
    DbMethods dbMethods;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);
    t1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.reguser);
    t2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.regemail);
    t3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.regpass);

    sp=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter ad=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.locations,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sp.setAdapter(ad);
    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    dbMethods=new DbMethods(this);
}

public void registerme(View v)
{
    String s1=t1.getText().toString();
    String s2=t2.getText().toString();
    String s3=t3.getText().toString();

    if(s1.isEmpty() || s2.isEmpty() || s3.isEmpty())
        Ding.ding(getApplicationContext(),"Enter all details!");
    else
    {
        long id=dbMethods.insertUser(s1,s2,s3);
        if(id<=0)
        {
            Ding.ding(getApplicationContext(),"Unsuccessful, Try Again!");
            t1.setText("");
            t2.setText("");
        }
        else
        {
            Ding.ding(getApplicationContext(),"Welcome "+t1.getText()+", Please Sign In!");
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    Intent i=new Intent(Registration.this,Login.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            },500);
        }
    }
}

public void regclr(View v)
{
    t1.setText("");
    t2.setText("");
    t3.setText("");
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l)
{
    TextView t=(TextView)view;
    loc=t.getText().toString();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) 
{

}
}
```

**HomeDbMethods.java-**

```
public class HomeDbMethods {

static class HomeDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    public HomeDbHelper(Context context)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1)
    {

    }
}
}
```

I can't find a proper solution on Internet, neither Google nor Stack OverFlow and now I don't know what to do with the above two classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you used below code for display record for selected value for spinner control and fetch data from database..
i hope you can insert data from database then i am only provide how to fetch record and show it..

below code used to fetch data from spinner value selected ..

```
    /*
       this method display a food data.
    */
public List<Food> displayRecord(String selectedValue)
{
    List<Food> mFood=new ArrayList<>();
    mDatabase=this.getReadableDatabase();
    String mQuery="select *from "+TABLE_NAME +" where foodName="+selectedValue;
    mCursor=mDatabase.rawQuery(mQuery,null);
    mCursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!mCursor.isAfterLast())
    {
        Food mObjFood=new Food();
        mObjFood.setmId(Integer.parseInt(mCursor.getString(0)));
        mObjFood.setmFoodName(mCursor.getString(1));
        mObjFood.setmFoodDes(mCursor.getString(2));
        byte [] image=mCursor.getBlob(mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_IMAGE));
        mObjFood.setmFoodImage(image);
        mFood.add(mObjFood);
        mCursor.moveToNext();
    }
    return mFood;
}
```

then after make recycler view adapter like below ...

```
public class FoodAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FoodAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
private List<Food> mFood;
public int mImpId;
private Context context;
public byte[] image;

public FoodAdapter(Context context, List<Food> mFood) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mFood = mFood;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardlayout, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(FoodAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Food mObjFood = mFood.get(position);
    image = mObjFood.getmFoodImage();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
    holder.mIvFoodImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    holder.mTvName.setText(mObjFood.getmFoodName());
    holder.mTvDes.setText(mObjFood.getmFoodDes());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mFood.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView mIvFoodImage;
    public TextView mTvName, mTvDes;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mIvFoodImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dsIvFoodImage);
        mTvName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dsTvFoodName);
        mTvDes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dsTvFoodDes);
    }
}
```

}

adapter define layout create layout and take image view,and two textview .
Note in xml parent layout height in wrape content..

then after main activity define recycler view and used below code in it..
this code used when spinner item user selected ..

```
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    List<Food> mFoodList=new ArrayList<>();
    FoodAdapter adpater;
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            mFoodList.clear();
            mFoodList=displayRecord(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
            adpater=new FoodAdapter(this,mFoodList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adpater.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```